# macOS 13 and 14 Uncontrollable Mouse Speed

Tags: macos, macbook-air, wireless-mouse, macos-monterey

The following problem started from macOS 13.6 (I guess) on M1 MacBook Air and it still exists.
I have an external Bluetooth/2.4 GHz Xiaomi mouse (whose brand or model does not make any difference for that matter) and starting from that update they don't seem to be controlled by macOS anymore. No matter what speed I set for the mouse (or other wireless mouses) in *System Settings* it does not change even a bit and the mouse speed is really fast like it's set to 3/4 of maximum speed. Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance. I have tried the following since then.

1. Setting the mouse speed using *Terminal* commands in **sudo** mode
2. Putting the mac into recovery mode and applying repairs
3. Completely deleting the *.plist* file for mouse settings
4. Using third-party apps like *LinearMouse*